# Removing all occurences of duplicates in a file on Unix

Tags: unix, awk, duplicates

I would like to remove both occurrences of duplicates from a file based on a number of columns. Here is a toy example:

Would like to delete all records that do not have uniqueness through the first 4 columns. So applying the `awk` script to:

```
    BLUE,CAR,RED,HOUSE,40
    BLUE,CAR,BLACK,HOUSE,20
    BLUE,CAR,GREEN,HOUSE,10
    BLUE,TRUCK,RED,HOUSE,40
    BLUE,TRUCK,GREEN,HOUSE,40
    BLUE,TRUCK,RED,HOUSE,40
```

Should result in

```
    BLUE,CAR,RED,HOUSE,40
    BLUE,CAR,BLACK,HOUSE,20
    BLUE,CAR,GREEN,HOUSE,10
    BLUE,TRUCK,GREEN,HOUSE,40
```

I have tried:

```
awk -F"," -v OFS="," '{cnt[$1,$2,$3,$4]++} END {for (rec in cnt) if (cnt[rec] == 1) print rec}' ss.txt
```

Which successfully removes both dupes, but does not apply the correct delimiter or print the whole record, resulting in:

```
    BLUECARREDHOUSE
    BLUETRUCKGREENHOUSE
    BLUECARBLACKHOUSE
    BLUECARGREENHOUSE
```

I prefer an `awk` solution but any *portable* solution is welcomed.

Comment: Do you want the extra data in the output (the 40 in the first record)?

Comment: Yes, the whole record should be printed even though the duplicate values are only being established on the first four fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you want the whole record for the records that are unique in the first 4 columns, this would do the job:

```
awk -F',' '{cnt[$1,$2,$3,$4]++;line[$1,$2,$3,$4] = $0}
           END {for (rec in cnt) if (cnt[rec] == 1) print line[rec]}' \
    ss.txt
```

Save the lines as well as the counts; get back what you entered.  This gets painful if you have gigabyte files; there are ways to only save the unique lines if you want. This only saves the first version of each line, and deletes an entry when it is known to be non-unique.  (Untested - but I believe it should work.  Modified per [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27950863/removing-all-occurances-of-duplicates-in-file-on-unix/27950960?noredirect=1#comment44297714_27950960) from [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton).)

```
awk -F',' '{ if (cnt[$1,$2,$3,$4]++ == 0)
                 line[$1,$2,$3,$4] = $0
             else
                 delete line[$1,$2,$3,$4]
           }
           END {for (rec in line) print line[rec]}' \
    ss.txt
```

If you only wanted the 4 key columns, then this just saves the 4 columns in the comma-separated format that you'll print:

```
awk -F',' '{cnt[$1,$2,$3,$4]++;line[$1,$2,$3,$4] = $1 "," $2 "," $3 "," $4}
           END {for (rec in cnt) if (cnt[rec] == 1) print line[rec]}' \
    ss.txt
```

Comment: for the untested one, you don't need to test `cnt` again, just make the END section `END {for (rec in line) print line[rec]}'`

Comment: @EdMorton: Yup - true enough.  (Strictly, they're all untested, but that was the one I was least sure of; the others look good based on experience.)  And I was squeezing in the answer in between compilations.

Comment: FWIW That last one could just be `awk 'BEGIN{FS=SUBSEP=","} {cnt[$1,$2,$3,$4]++} END{for (rec in cnt) if (cnt[rec] == 1) print rec}'`

Comment: @EdMorton: Yup - that too.  There wasn't enough time spent polishing the code, but that's somewhat unavoidable on occasion.